# Can I build a solid website without using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, build, web

I'm just starting to learn web development and I've been wondering If I can build solid websites using only HTML, CSS and maybe some PHP.
I don't want anything complicated I wanna start simple just to get used to those languages before starting to learn JS because I feel it's a bit more complicated and I'm not good with programming languages.
I wanna be able to create something like this: http://enactus.org/

Comment: The website you linked uses a **lot** of JavaScript.

Comment: http://www.create-a-website-with-html.com

Comment: There's no maths and if/then statements in PHP?

Comment: @Teemu I'm not learning PHP yet so I don't know..I just started HTML/CSS.

Comment: You'll be dissapointed, [but...](http://php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php) ; ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment so i'll post as an answer. So please no down voting.
You can create a website but that site won't be an interactive website. What I mean is that the site will not be able to get data from users and save it in databases (well you can if you wan't to use some php but php is also more on the math, logic and stuffs that you would typically use on javascript.), or buttons that would do stuffs without refreshing the website...  So to summarize it if you want to learn website designing first HTML and CSS is a way to go and also can be a great start for beginners like us. And if you want your site to be interactive start learning Javascript and PHP.

Comment: You also absolutely can build a website that stores user information in a database without using javascript. I'm thinking of frameworks like Spring, Django, and Flask, just to name the few that I am acquainted with.